# Can not decode a different version encoded JWT token

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-4, jwt

I'm trying to figure out why Laravel 5.8 / `"tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.12"` JWT token created `fromUser()` is failing to be decoded in Laravel 4 / `"tymon/jwt-auth": "0.4.*"`.

Trying to debug for the past 4 hours... I'm 100% sure the secret and headers are the same as they are loaded from the config file.

Did anyone dealt with a similar problem?

Comment: This will not answer your question, but take a look at this https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1863 : this library lacks a proper access/refresh-token setup and it is also used as a stateful web token, meaning that you might as well use a regular laravel session. The default implementation of `tymon/jwt-auth` is just mediocre. Depending on what your usecase is you might want to take a better look at what youre using.

Comment: Tell me about it... I have another API which is based on `firebase/php-jwt` and has no issues with decoding. I'm sure its `tymon/jwt-auth` or the encoding dependency issue, however, can't seem to be able to debug it.